# Find all disabled fields and addClass jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find all disabled fields under body tag and addClass("disabeldFields") using jquery. Below is my code :

HTML :

```
<input id="btnOk" value="Ok" type="button"/>
<input id="text1" type="text" disabled/>
<input id="text2" type="text"/>
<input id="text3" type="text" disabled/>
```

Jquery :

```
$("#btnOk").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("body").find($(*).prop('disabled')).addClass("disabeldFields");
});
```

Its not working. How can I do it ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you're looking for styling disabled inputs, use CSS. `input[disabled] { background: gray; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('body').find('input:disabled').addClass('disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btnOk" value="Ok" type="button"/>
<input id="text1" type="text" disabled/>
<input id="text2" type="text"/>
<input id="text3" type="text" disabled/>
```

Use [:disabled](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector

> Description: Selects all elements that are disabled.

Comment: @Ikr glad to help pls tick the accepted answer to reduce unanswered question in SO

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("body input:disabled").each(function () {
                alert(this);
                $(this).addClass("disabeldFields");
            });
        });
```